# Cannot ssh into BeagleBone Black Wireless over wifi

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

I have connected successfully to my wifi through the BeagleBone Black Wireless (BBB Wireless) using the `connmanctl` and can even see my BBB wireless assigned a local ip address by my wifi. I want to be able to use the BBB Wireless by ssh through wifi and connected to a power source other than my computer. But when I try to `ssh` to it over the same ip I keep getting the error: `ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.35 port 22: No route to host`.

When I try pinging `192.168.1.35`, i.e. the ip address assigned by my wifi to the BBB wireless, I get:

```
From 192.168.1.37 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.37 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.37 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.37 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.37 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.37 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.37 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.37 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.37 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.1.35 ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 0 received, +9 errors, 100% packet loss, time 11268ms
pipe 4
```

I am very sure of the ip address assigned by my wifi to the BBB Wireless which I'm trying to ssh to. There's no way to access the BBB wireless via ssh except for when I have it connected to my computer via USB. It also does not have an ethernet port and the only way to access it is by connecting it to the wifi or the computer via USB.

**Observations:**
When I have the BBB wireless connected to the power source, I see a new wifi hotspot named `BeagleBone-1E7E` all the while. I can also see the device connected on my wifi's list of connected devices.

Comment: what is the IP address of the host you are pinging from?   Is it also a wifi client or is it wired ethernet?

Comment: I'm pinging from my laptop connected to the wifi.

Comment: Does your router allow wifi-to-wifi communication?  Many routers will block wifi clients from talking to each other.  This is usually a setting somewhere in the router config.  Look for guest or station isolation settings.